# How to find increment in length of rope due to its own weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stress-strain

I used stress/strain = Young modulus and am getting mgl/AY. . where m=mass l=length A=cross-sectional area and  Y= young modulus.The correct answer is mgl/2AY. Where is my mistake?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is stating that the stretching force is $mg$.

That is true for the very (infinitesimal) top of the rope but the bottom (infinitesimal) end of the rope does not have a force on it and so it does not stretch.

A clue to this is in the answer that you have given which you can interpret by having the average force as $\frac {mg}{2}$.

What you need to do is to split the rope into elements of length $dx$ at a distance of $x$ from the bottom of the rope and find the weight of the rope below that element $dx$ and hence find the extension of that element.
Then do an integration over the whole rope to get your required answer.

Comment: But for problems with a block hanging from the end of a wire of a given radius,length,modulus I equated stress/strain to Young modulus to find the extension and got the answer too.There I took the stress due to Tension only and not due to the wires own weight.There also the top part should be under more stress than bottom but I got the answer without integrating.How?

Comment: In those problems, the weight of the wire might have been neglected relative to the weight of the block. Thus, the tension in the top of the wire might have been assumed to equal the tension in the bottom of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have taken the force on each element to be constant. In reality, the force on any element at distance x from the top will be $\rho *Area* dx$, where rho is the density. Now, you have to integrate it from 0 to L to find the correct answer.